# positioning with CSS so that div would not move

Tags: html, css

As you can see i have a `image A` and `image B` now when i click on `object 1` an `iframe` comes up as shown in `image B` but `object 2` goes to the bottom how can i fix this with CSS please help.
[image]

Comment: Add `position: absolute` on the iframe

Comment: Wow that was simple lol Thanks a lot @Guy 
by the way do you know how i can make that iframe oblique so that the background wouldn't show of the other page hope u can understand what i am saying

Comment: No worries, I added an answer below. Regarding the transparent background on the iframe, you wont be able to change it from the page its loaded into, but if you have control of the iframe structure you can just set the `body` to have `background-color: transparent`, so it will be see through when loaded into the page.

Comment: i do have control over that iframe its directed to 
but i do not want it to be transparent  i want it to come up as a box therefore hiding the black bar

Comment: Ah sorry, got the wrong end of the stick. To make it solid you can apply the same logic but reversed. So add `body { background-color: white }` for example

Comment: now this worked but what i did was `<iframe style=" background-color: white ;" />` 
this and it worked thanks you have been a great help man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By making the iframe `position: absolute` you can take it out of the flow of the document and stop it from forcing your other elements down the page.

Something like the following should achieve what you are looking for I believe:

```
.header iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px; /* this should be the height of your top (black) bar */
  left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to have them on the same line, all you need to do is `display: inline;` to both of your objects, then to move them to other spots on the same page use the 4 ways to move them: `padding-top`, `padding-bottom,` `padding-left`, and `padding-right`. For example:

```css
.object1 {
     display: inline;
     padding-top: 100px;
}
```